# Evaluation of Dynamic Variable for Tkinter Button command function

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I am making  an interface to display available com ports as buttons and, when pressed to pass the com name to a variable.  Currently I can make dynamic buttons but I am having trouble passing the values to an outside function.

The code creates two buttons for com7 and com8 (current ports on my system) with a dictionary in which i[1]=com7 and i[2]=com8.  When I press the button for i[1] I get a Keyerror because the current value of K is now 3, which is not a key in the dictionary. Obviously I want the button to reference the value of K when it was created, not the current value of K.

Essentially I want python to evaluate i[k] at the moment of button creation, not at the moment the button is pressed.

```
import serial, sys, os, Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

def com():
    global ser
    global p

    def pget(inport):
        print inport
        test.destroy()


    test=Tk()

    try:
        from serial.tools.list_ports import comports
    except ImportError:
        comports = None
        V = ""
        while V is "" :
            for port, desc, hwid in sorted(comports()):
                print "\nAvailable Ports:\n"
                V =sys.stderr.write(' %-10s %s\n' % (port, desc))
            if V is "":
                print "No ports available, plug in COM port and hit ENTER"
                raw_input()
    def Port():
        i={}
        k=1
        if comports:
            l=Label(test, text="Available ports:").pack(side=TOP)
            sys.stderr.write('\n Available ports:\n')
        for port, desc, hwid in sorted(comports()):
            print port
            i[k]=port
            bport=Button(test,text=port+": "+desc,command=lambda: pget(i[k])).pack()
            print k, i[k]
            k+=1
        test.mainloop()
    Port()


com()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
bport=Button(test,text=port+": "+desc,command=lambda: pget(i[k])).pack()
```

To:

```
bport=Button(test,text=port+": "+desc,command=lambda port = i[k]: pget(port))
bport.pack()
```

This forces the value to be sent in to `pget()` to be set at creation of the Button rather than when `mainloop()` is initiated.

I also moved `pack()` to another line (this is a rare case of saving lines not being a good practice).  If you were to try to refer back to `bport` it would be referencing the what the method `pack()` returns, which is always `None`.

Separating the method call and the object creation will prevent this.

Comment: Thank you, you just gave me an epiphany about using lambda with tkinter!

Comment: You're welcome, and as a side note... It is generally not a good idea to create the Tkinter object and use `pack()` on the same expression.  This means that `bport` refers to the `pack()` method rather than the button object itself.

Comment: Small correction: when using `pack()` (or `grid` or `place` for that matter) on the same line as the creation of the button, the variable will not refer to the `pack()` method, but it will contain whatever `pack()` returns, which is always `None`.

Comment: I forget the power and syntax of lambda related work. Great answer.